# Sklearn use train_test_split while controlling ratios between classes

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When using scikit-learn's `train_test_split` tool, I would like to split the data while controlling the ratio between classes. Here's the problem:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from collections import Counter

x_coords = range(100)
labels = ['a']*90 + ['b']*10
x_train, x_test, label_train, label_test = train_test_split(x_coords, labels, test_size=20)

print(Counter(label_test))
```

which gives: `'a':18, 'b':2`. Another random split gives `'a':20`.

So 20 samples were randomly chosen, but labeling was ignored. I would like to have control over the ratios between the classes. I'm currently this manually, by using `train_test_split` to split each class separately into a train and test set, and then re-combine all of the test and training sets. Does anyone know a more elegant, sklearn-based way to do this?

I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082001/how-to-split-a-dataset-into-training-and-validation-set-keeping-ratio-between-cl) that this can be done so that the ratios between the classes in the original data is maintained, but I would like to specify the ratios myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to split a dataset into training and validation set keeping ratio between classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082001/how-to-split-a-dataset-into-training-and-validation-set-keeping-ratio-between-cl)

Comment: @MiltonArangoG I am not sure - OP asks for *controlling* the ratio, not simply maintain it

Comment: What you want will in my opinion go into subsampling problems.