# How can I evenly split a dataset with uneven classes

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dataset

I have a dataset that I am trying to use with a neural network.

The real data looks something like

```
import numpy as np

features = np.random.rand(1000, 5)
labels = np.array([1 if sum(e)>1 else 0 for e in features])
```

so roughly 80% of my samples will have the label `1` and the rest will have the label `0`.

I can split this into training and testing data using a scikit-learn function

```
from sklearn import

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=0.9)
```

But this will make my training data be strongly skewed, and not very representative of the `0` label. I would like to split my data so that there are as many `0`s as there are `1`s in the training sample.

---

I could do this by hand

```
# separate 1s and 0s
feat0 = np.array([a if b==0 for a, b in zip(features, labels)])
feat1 = np.array([a if b==1 for a, b in zip(features, labels)])
labl0 = np.zeros((len(labels)-sum(labels)))
labl1 = np.ones((sum(labels)))

# split into training and testing sets
x_train0, x_test0, y_train0, y_test0 = train_test_split(feat0, labl0, test_size=0.5)
x_train1, x_test1, y_train1, y_test1 = train_test_split(feat1, labl1, test_size=0.5)

# recombine
x_train = np.concatenate(x_train0[:100], x_train1[:100])
y_train = np.concatenate(y_train[:100], y_train[:100])
```

but I would like to know if there is a built-in function to do this, or perhaps a more elegant way.

---

I looked at `StratifiedKFold`, but

> The folds are made by preserving the percentage of samples for each class.

and this is not what I want to do. I want to force a different percentage of samples for each class.

The `1` to `0` ratio in my initial dataset is 80/20. The ratio I want in my training set is 50/50. How do I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to split a dataset into training and validation set keeping ratio between classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082001/how-to-split-a-dataset-into-training-and-validation-set-keeping-ratio-between-cl)

Comment: Not quite. I don't want to preserve the ratio from the global set but rather force a 50/50 ratio between both classes.

Comment: Also, the answer to that question appears to be outdated.